# .addItem for combobox is not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, combobox

Ok to start I made a jframe with the built in jFrame creator for netbeans. I added a combobo (jcbClass) and in the model options in bottom right of screen I added a few items. So I double clicked the combobox to add more items to jcbClass based on the previous combobox's selected item.

but when I run the program and change the race combobox nothing more is added to jcbClass. I have tested jcb.addItem("bob"); in many places just to see if it even adds it to the combobox in the first place and it does not. Please help I am quite frustrated over this simple task.

Re: I have done lots of research but cant understand why it is not working.

```
   /*
Author: *****
Start Date: June 30 2016
End Date:
Info: Basic start for game and gets user input
 */

/**
 *
 * @author 8022307
 */
public class firstTimeStart extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form firstTimeStart
     */
    public firstTimeStart() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jtfNameInput = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jlName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jcbRace = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jlRace = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jlClass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jcbClass = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        jbDone = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JSeparator();
        jlTitleTwo = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Legends Of The Eclipse");
        setName("jlTitle"); // NOI18N
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 500));
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Legends Of The Eclipse");

        jtfNameInput.setText("Name Goes Here");
        jtfNameInput.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jtfNameInputActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jlName.setText("Name");

        jcbRace.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Elf", "Ork", "Human", "Dwarf", "Demon", "Angel" }));

        jlRace.setText("Race");

        jlClass.setText("Class");

        jcbClass.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Ranger", "Assassin", "Rogue", "Archane Warrior", "Monk", "Wizard" }));
        jcbClass.setName(""); // NOI18N
        jcbClass.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jcbClassActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jbDone.setText("Done");

        jlTitleTwo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 18)); // NOI18N
        jlTitleTwo.setText("Final Choice Check");

        jLabel2.setText("jLabel2");

        jLabel3.setText("jLabel3");

        jLabel4.setText("jLabel4");

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(115, 115, 115))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jlTitleTwo)
                        .addGap(176, 176, 176))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jlRace)
                                    .addComponent(jlClass))
                                .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jtfNameInput)
                                    .addComponent(jcbRace, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jcbClass, 0, 120, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                            .addComponent(jlName)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 516, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jbDone)
                        .addGap(222, 222, 222))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(220, 220, 220))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlName)
                    .addComponent(jtfNameInput, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jcbRace, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jlRace))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jlClass)
                    .addComponent(jcbClass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jbDone)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jSeparator1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jlTitleTwo)
                .addGap(4, 4, 4)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(11, 11, 11)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(133, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jtfNameInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    }                                            

    private void jcbClassActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        if (jcbRace.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Elf")){
            jcbClass.addItem("bob");
        }


    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(firstTimeStart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(firstTimeStart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(firstTimeStart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(firstTimeStart.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new firstTimeStart().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jbDone;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jcbClass;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jcbRace;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlClass;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlRace;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jlTitleTwo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jtfNameInput;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I see that you've edited your post, but what you've posted does not help **us** understand your problem or why it's not working. Instead strongly consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. This would be posted as code-formatted text and not in a link.

Comment: ok thanks (sorry first post and did not know how much to add), i have the gui which has all the extra stuff i did not program, will post in a second

Comment: Thanks for the post, but you're posting a heck of a lot of code completely unrelated to the problem at hand. Please note the part above, `"We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem."`, as well as you should read or re-read the [mcve] link. Please remember that we're volunteers, so please try to be kind to us and not overwhelm us with unrelated code.

Comment: And your ActionListener **does** work, but you didn't add it to a JButton but rather to the other JComboBox.

Comment: Im sincerly sorry, cause I am working with the built in gui i figured it would not run without the  major code parts, I am so sorry and thank you for putting up with me and answering.

Comment: All you need to do is create a JPanel, stuff your JComboBoxes, buttons and text fields into it, display the JPanel in a JFrame or JOptionPane, and that would suffice, maybe 30 to 40 lines of code.

Comment: Ok thank you, will definitely try that thanks